# No puedo Leer el archivo excel en forma corrida en Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, studio

Hola amigos me pueden ayudar lo que pasa quiero leer un excel en listView pero me sale las palabaras debajo y no como quiero en forma lineal ejemplo 1 T1 MUS PACHECO

```
 @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun LecturaExcel(uri: Uri) {
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        try {
            val wp = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream)
            val s: Sheet = wp.getSheet(0)
            val row = s.rows
            val col = s.columns
            var xx = ""
            var z: Cell? = null
            for (i in 0 until row) {
                for (c in 0 until col) {
                    z = s.getCell(c, i)
                    xx = " " + z!!.contents
                    listas.add(xx)
                }

                 xx += "\n"
            }
```

Comment: Revisa [ask] , que usas ademàs de Kotlin? revisaste el LogCat?

Comment: Deseo leer los datos de excel en un listview, Pero al hacerlo como el código que publique, no me lee como se esperara si no sale duplicado en un mismo ítem